# Queued jobs with individual max number of tries, how to?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Normally, the max tries are specified on the queue level like so:

```
php artisan queue:listen connection-name --tries=3
```

I would like to be able to override this (without affecting other jobs) on the job level within the job class.

I can think of three ways to go about this but they may not be elegant:

1. Set a high number of tries on queue level
2. Look into the failed queue and retry the job
3. Create a new job upon failure

Note:

1. My case is related to polling via API.
2. I am recording my poll attempts within my own model.

Answer (score 7):

Try use `attempts()` method to check current job attempt in the job class. Something like below.

```
class MyJobClass implements ShouldQueue
{

    public function handle()
    {
        if ($this->attempts() < 3) {
            // do job things
        }
        else {
            // delete job
        }
    }
}
```

Reference on laravel repository https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.php#L21

Comment: Each attempt still count towards the --tries setting no? Which means that the --tries will need to be set greater than the "3" in your example. And therefore, all jobs in the queue will be affected.

If there was a way to release the job back into the queue without counting the attempt, other jobs won't be affected.

Comment: you may add on `else` to delete the job using `$this->delete()` so it will not continue the tries until max counts

Answer (score 5):

Since Laravel 5.4, you can specifiy `$tries` on the job class to override the number of attempts for that job

```
    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 5;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout